# Check if user has provided image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using these gem's to handle my image uploader:

```
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'mini_magick'
gem 'fog'
```

However I can't seem to find out whether or not the image is nil or empty, as it can't be because it returns this when I call @user.picture:

> ## "********@hotmail.co.uk", encrypted_password:
>
> "************************************",
>   reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil,
>   remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 6, current_sign_in_at:
>   "2016-03-18 11:23:00", last_sign_in_at: "2016-03-18 11:18:16",
>   current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1",
>   created_at: "2016-03-17 15:00:46", updated_at: "2016-03-18 11:24:13",
>   provider: nil, uid: nil, username: "StormViper", login: nil, cart_id:
>   1, admin: true, picture: "download.jpg", brand_id: 1, is_brand?:
>   true>, @mounted_as=:picture,
>   @storage=#>,
>   @file=#, @versions={}>

This is my user controller:

```
if @user.save
  p "USER SAVED LOGIN: #{@user.username}"
  @cart = Cart.create(:user_id => @user.id, :cart_count => 0)
  @cart.save
  @user.cart_id = @cart.id
  @user.save

  @slot = Slot.create(:cart_id => @cart.id)
  @slot.save
  @cart.slot_id = @slot.id
  @cart.save
  redirect_to root_path
else
  p "USER FAILED LOGIN: #{@user.username}"
  render 'new'
end
```

How would I solve this issue? I can't directly change the picture.url as it returns:

> *** NoMethodError Exception: undefined method `url=' for
>
> ## PictureUploader:0x007f73e6135e78>

My user model contains:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :cart
  has_many :slots, through: :carts
  belongs_to :brand
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  attr_accessor :login
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
         :authentication_keys => [:login]
  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true
    def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
      conditions = warden_conditions.dup
      if login = conditions.delete(:login)
        where(conditions.to_hash).where(["lower(username) = :value OR lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
      elsif conditions.has_key?(:username) || conditions.has_key?(:email)
        where(conditions.to_hash).first
      end
    end
    mount_uploader :picture, PictureUploader
end
```

Comment: What's in your `User` model? Can you update your post with that info?

Comment: I have just added my User model

Comment: Thanks, I'll put an answer now.

Comment: did you run migration after generate it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you do have something saved to the picture column on your user. If you're looking for a boolean, I'd try `@user.picture.present?`, and if you're looking for the actual file, `@user.picture.url`.

Edit: `#url`, not `#file` on the Carrierwave upload models. I was confusing work with home for a second!

Comment: Thank you, however how would I set the @user.picture.url? as I get a ''NoMethodError for PictureUploader'' when I try to set it

Comment: You would set `@user.picture`. `#url` is just a getter method that Carrierwave provides, and the urls aren't meant to be edited directly.

Comment: That said, if you want to change what urls are generated, you might take a look at the "Changing the storage directory" section from the Carrierwave docs - https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#changing-the-storage-directory.

Comment: Is there a way to set the image if one isn't provided?

Comment: Yup! You can override `#default_url` in your uploader: https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#providing-a-default-url

Answer (score 0):

You will get your user picture url by

```
@user.picture_url and check @user.picture_url.present?
```